# OrientDB no way to screening keywords

Tags: orientdb

How to avoid incorrect query parsing?

In next example class name `Contains` parsed as keyword:

```
CREATE EDGE Contains FROM #14:0 TO #14:1
```

Return exception "Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #0: Encountered "  "Contains "" at line 1, column 13."

But I can create Edge class without any exception:

```
CREATE CLASS Contains EXTENDS E
```

In OrientDB v2.1.0 next query worked correctly:

```
CREATE EDGE `Contains` FROM #14:0 TO #14:1
```

But in 2.1.1 it's again broken (as I know in older versions screening by `` ` `` also not supported).

---

## Solved

Bug was found in versions 2.1.1-2.1.2, now it fixed (https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4980).

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a question. If you know that back ticks were working, and now they are broken, then perhaps you should post in the OrientDB issue tracker, or forum. But better yet, why not just use a different class name, like 'Holds' or 'Has', in order to not conflict with "reserved keywords"?

Comment: @neRok , in my case class name generated automatically by script, so I can't predict what class name can be incorrect parsed in future. `Contains` is just example. Now this bug fixed in [issue #4980](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/4980), thanks for advice.